# Vertically align time series (plot and barplot) sharing same x-axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, visualization

Is there an easy way to align two subplots of a time series of different kinds (plot and barplot) in matplotlib? I use the pandas wrapper since I am dealing with `pd.Series` objects:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
series = pd._testing.makeTimeSeries()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)
series.head(3).plot(marker='o', ax=axes[0])
series.head(3).plot.bar(ax=axes[1])
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: example]

The result is not visually great, it would be great to keep the code simplicity and:

- Vertically align data points in the top plot to the bars on the bottom plot
- Share the axis of the bar plot with the first and remove the visibility on x-axis labels of the top plot altogether (but keep grids whenever present)

Comment: Try `plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)`

Comment: @scleronomic 's proposal would work in case you create the line and bar plot both via matplotlib (`plt.plot`, `plt.bar`); but not with pandas plotting functions. With pandas your only chance is to set the limits manually, such that they visually fit.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Did not know that. I tried it and the sharing worked but only one of the plots is displayed, strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the ideas thrown in the comments, I think that this is the simplest solution (giving up the pandas API), which is exactly what I needed:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
series = pd._testing.makeTimeSeries()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
axes[0].plot(series.head(3), marker='o')
axes[1].bar(series.head(3).index, series.head(3))
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: solution]

With eventual fix on the xticks for cases with missing values, where the xticks are not plotted daily (e.g. `plt.xticks(series.head(3).index)`).

Thanks for the help!